# Maven build on Eclipse: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, out-of-memory

I know this has been asked multiple times before, but no solution worked so far in my case.

**Situation:** I'm trying to build a Maven project. The environment is JDK 1.7 on Eclipse.

**Problem:** Upon running a Maven build, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

**What I've tried** : In my pom.xml I tried from other StackOverFlow answers:

```
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
                        <maxmem>1048m</maxmem>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
```

I also changed the memory settings in eclipse.ini

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the vm-arguments of the runconfig of your Maven build? 
It may help to adjust the memory size here.
For example, add -Xms1024M

Comment: Hi tgallei. Does this also have to be set in pom.xml as I tried the -Xmx parameter above ?

Comment: Java 7? Really? Are you using an outdated Eclipse and an outdated Maven too? Fix this first, everything else might be caused by that.

Comment: @howlger if you end maintaining a legacy project in a corporate environment you don't always have the luxury of choosing which technology you use. I know since I'm still maintaining a Java **6** application for an enterprise customer.

Comment: I agree with @howlger. In this case too my hands are tied, unless the client spends a few million dollars to migrate (rewrite) the code, servers etc. onto new platforms.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Targeting an older Java 6 version does not require to use outdated tools. With Eclipse 2019-12 you can create Java 1.3 bytecode and with a Java 9 or higher JDK you can use the `--release` argument to create down to Java 6 bytecode without even having a Java 6 JDK. For security reasons, you should run your Java 6 and 7 application on a Java 8 VM.

Comment: Please try to build on plain command line not within Eclipse or any other IDE...

Comment: Earlier I meant I agree with @Frederico.

howgler, the client doesn't allow me to download an upgraded version of Notepad++. Upgrading to new platforms will take months of negotiations and contracts with high-salaried MBA managers on both sides.

Comment: @howlger as OP pointed out, you don't always choose your tools either. Customer mandates we use *their* machines to do development work. And guess what's installed there? Windows Server 2003, Eclipse Galileo, JDeveloper 11g, etc... I mean, not all our clients are like this, but one is. And they pay. So should I just say "naaa, you use outdated tech, won't work with you"? Guess what, they use COBOL as well.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca At the latest when there are no security updates for an outdated version anymore, upgrade. It's that simple. Sometimes you have to explain this to a decision maker without the technical knowledge. Most of us have faced this situation more than one time. In this case, not a single line of code has to be rewritten. On the other hand, outdated software means a high risk, which can cause high costs.

Comment: @howlger I know, I'm not talking about best practices. I'm talking about the worst scenario. Which happens. My point was that "just upgrade" is not always feasible. I know it **should** be done and would be for the best in the medium/long run. But sometimes you have to contend with stupid/risk-averse/ignorant people on the customer side and you have no way of firing them. So you have people asking about legacy tech and saying "you should upgrade" doesn't help. That's all, I don't want to pick a fight over this :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Decision makers are not _"stupid/risk-averse/ignorant people"_, but choose what costs less. Instead of explaining the technical aspects of an upgrade (_oh, some extras we didn't need before_), ask whether to continue to use the outdated tool, even if that means spending significantly more time. Ask how much time is planned to handle the consequences of the missed security updates. They take the risk and a later update is more expensive and that's why almost everybody does it. Remember, you have the same choice for your job: upgrade or not to upgrade. ;)

Comment: @howlger In my specific case it's just that, historically, vendors changed frequently. But they still had to support the existing stuff .Result: unmanageable mess of vendors/platforms/versions where changing anything would break everything else (it happened). You can give all the reasons you want for why this is wrong,and you're perfectly right, but the situation doesn't change. Place like this just exist. And I have no problem working like this. I'm just saying sometimes you'll get question on SO where "upgrade" is not the correct answer for a specific situation.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I disagree. Technical rules, such as not to upgrade, even if technically possible, are off-topic on Stack Overflow. What would you say to a client using and complaining about the stuff you developed years ago, missing all the improvements and fixes you spend so much work on? Do you think this is fair to developers of open source that you use for free?

Comment: "What would you say to a client using and complaining about the stuff you developed years ago, missing all the improvements and fixes you spend so much work on?" I'd say "That's what you told me to use, right here in the contract". And I don't understand your point about the open source stuff I supposedly use (you mean Weblogic, Websphere, DB2, RAD or what? Nothing other than eclipse is open source in the stack the customer uses).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Take a closer look to see what all is open source: Linux, Java, Maven, language/protocol spezifications, most libraries, etc. If you use open source, the license is the contract. In most cases it is not allowed to modify open source without publishing the changes. In fact, this happens quite often. If you stand on the shoulders of giants, don't piss on them. And by the way, I haven't had or heard about a contract that would not allow to upgrade.

Comment: @howlger I have no idea how we went from "customer dictates technology" to "you're pissing on OS devs". The contract is between me and my customer. The software is for internal use. OS licenses apply only as far as I have to provide the the source code for the libraries (which *they* chose) to the client. Really, I have no idea what you're talking about and how it has anything to do with the fact that "just upgrade" is not always the correct answer (since the discussion was originally about that).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca For me it is not okay to reject upgrading as an answer except for technical reasons because anything non-technical on Stack Overflow is off-topic. Do you agree that we disagree on this point? Further, if and only if it is open source software, IMHO it is unfair not to upgrade.

Comment: *"Do you agree that we disagree on this point?"* absolutely :D *"Further, if and only if it is open source software, IMHO it is unfair not to upgrade."* if you mean the end result is open source software then I *absolutely agree*, but I don't see how this has anything to do with the question or anything that's been discussed up until now.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Performance improvements have been made in recent versions of Maven. However, both answers here say to use `-Xmx` instead of to use the current Maven version that is faster and requires less memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying this on a Linux machine, set MAVEN_OPTS as below and see.

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"

Answer (score 1):

@tagellei gave the correct answer (in the comments section). Thanks @tagellei

Right-click on the project --> Run As --> Run Configurations --> Click the JRE Tab on the pop-up window --> Under VM arguments, type: -Xms512M -Xmx1024M